# how can I get small signal voltage gain

Tags: circuit-analysis

[image]

the question is to find the small signal voltage gain(vo/vs).

I found out that vo = 1/3(vb+vs).

and the nonlinear resistor acts as an amplifier when 3 < vb < 8!

how can I get small signal voltage gain from here?

Comment: To obtain a linear expression from a nonlinear formula, you can a) perturb the initial equation and sort out ac and dc terms b) use partial differentiation to get the ac terms only. You will find a lot of information in this seminar: http://cbasso.pagesperso-orange.fr/Downloads/PPTs/Chris%20Basso%20APEC%20seminar%202013.pdf

Comment: The 'vo' equation is incorrect, unless you remove the nonlinear device (make its current contribution zero).

Answer (score 2):

The gain depends on the bias voltage \$V_B\$.
For \$v_o < 1V\$, 

the non-linear element (NL) will behave as an open circuit as \$i = 0\$. Thus gain is given by voltage divider or \$A_v = \frac{1}{3}\$.
This happens for \$V_B < 3\$.
For \$1V < v_o < 2V\$,
The NL behaves as a resistor in series with 1V voltage source. To calculate the small signal gain we will short this source so \$A_v = \frac{0.5}{2.5} = 0.2\$
This happens for \$ 3V<V_B < 8V\$
For \$v_o > 2V\$,
The NL behaves as a current source (CS) so its small signal gain will again be \$\frac{1}{3}\$. Because CS acts as a small signal open.
This would happen for \$V_B > 8V\$

Answer (score 0):

Can you draw a simple graph with the input voltage on the x-axis, and the output voltage on the y-axis? It will be a piecewise-linear graph, with transitions between different linear sections corresponding to the various sections of the nonlinear resistor element.

Since there is no time-dependent behavior to this circuit (i.e. no capacitors and inductors), the small signal voltage gain is just relating an incremental input to an incremental output voltage.

Once you have this graph, you'd just need to determine its slope at the point of interest. Graphically, the slope is literally the ratio between incremental output for an incremental input.

This simulation models your nonlinear element:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fK30Ir.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The DC Sweep simulation shows the input-output curve described. The Frequency Domain simulation is used to examine the small-signal gain, and it's set up to run this gain calculation at a few different voltage bias points.